# Retornar todos os itens iguais de grupos diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
-------------------
- TABLE           -
-------------------
ID | GRUPO | OBJETO
---|-------|-------
1  | 1     | 1
2  | 1     | 2
   |       |
3  | 2     | 1
4  | 2     | 2
   |       |
5  | 3     | 1
6  | 3     | 2
7  | 3     | 3
   |       |
5  | 4     | 1
6  | 4     | 3
   |       |
7  | 5     | 1
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta para retornar todos os grupos que contém *exatamente* os mesmos *objetos*. Já usei *subquery* com `IN` mas os *objetos* *1* e *2* também estão no *grupo 3*.

Por exemplo, se eu consultar usando `where GRUPO = 1`, preciso que retorne apenas um total de dois registros (o grupo 1 e o grupo 2).

Os objetos do grupo 1 (*1* e *2*), também estão no grupo 2. Mas o grupo 3 contém um objeto além, o grupo 4 contém dois objetos mas um deles é diferente dos do grupo 1, e o grupo 5 contém apenas um objeto; logo, os grupos 3, 4 e 5 não devem ser considerados.

Há alguns relacionamentos mas não fazem muita diferença no caso.

---

- Grupo 1 comprou: laranja e maçã
- Grupo 2 comprou: laranja e maçã
- Grupo 3 comprou: laranja, maçã e banana

Se eu consultar pelo `GRUPO = 1`, preciso retornar *SÓ e SOMENTE* quem mais comprou ***APENAS*** *laranja e maçã*. Não quero saber em quais grupos *laranja e maçã* estão, por isso `IN` não funciona.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Penso que a seguinte solução devolve o resultado que pretendes.

Esta query devolve todos os grupos que têm exactamente os mesmos elementos que o grupo 1.

```
SELECT T.GRUPO
FROM   TESTE T
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT T1.OBJECTO,
         (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T2.OBJECTO) 
            FROM TESTE T2
           WHERE T2.GRUPO = T1.GRUPO) TOTAL
  FROM TESTE T1
  WHERE T1.GRUPO = 1   --filtras aqui o grupo
) SS
  ON SS.OBJECTO = T.OBJECTO
GROUP BY T.GRUPO
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T.OBJECTO) = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SS.OBJECTO IS NOT NULL THEN SS.OBJECTO END)
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT T.OBJECTO) = MAX(TOTAL)
```

**A lógica por trás desta query é a seguinte:**

A subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.OBJECTO,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T2.OBJECTO) 
          FROM TESTE T2
         WHERE T2.GRUPO = T1.GRUPO) TOTAL
FROM TESTE T1
WHERE T1.GRUPO = 1
```

tem como objectivo retornar todos os objectos do grupo 1. Esta é a base para o processo. Inicialmente, esta instrução apenas retornava os objectos, foi necessário alterar para retornar também o número total de objectos.

Com este resultado temos tudo o que é necessário para procurar os restantes grupos que têm exactamente os mesmos elementos. Isso é feito através das seguintes instruções:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T.OBJECTO) = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SS.OBJECTO IS NOT NULL THEN SS.OBJECTO END)
AND COUNT(DISTINCT T.OBJECTO) = MAX(TOTAL)
```

A primeira significa, "todos os elementos do grupo **(COUNT(DISTINCT T.OBJECTO))** têm que estar no grupo 1 **(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SS.OBJECTO IS NOT NULL THEN SS.OBJECTO END))**"

Finalmente, a instrução **COUNT(DISTINCT T.OBJECTO) = MAX(TOTAL)** guarante que o grupo tem que possuir o mesmo número de elementos que o grupo 1. Esta instrução é fundamental para excluir os grupos que, como no teu exemplo, apenas têm laranja. Laranja está no grupo 1 mas está fantando a maçã.

O MAX é necessário porque na instrução HAVING apenas podemos usar funções de agregação ou constantes.

Se quiseres obter os objectos para cada um dos grupos (os objectos serão sempre iguais), basta usar a query anterior para filtrar os resultados, por exemplo assim

```
SELECT T.GRUPO,
       T.OBJECTO
FROM   TESTE T
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT T.GRUPO
    FROM   TESTE T
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT T1.OBJECTO,
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T2.OBJECTO) 
               FROM TESTE T2
              WHERE T2.GRUPO = T1.GRUPO) TOTAL
      FROM TESTE T1
     WHERE T1.GRUPO = 1    --filtras aqui o grupo
    ) SS
      ON SS.OBJECTO = T.OBJECTO
    GROUP BY T.GRUPO
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T.OBJECTO) = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN SS.OBJECTO IS NOT NULL THEN SS.OBJECTO END)
       AND COUNT(DISTINCT T.OBJECTO) = MAX(TOTAL)
) X
  ON T.GRUPO = X.GRUPO
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Fica aqui também o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b33a5/11)

Comment: Funcionou maravilhosamente bem. Poderia dar uma ligeira comentada por alto, só pra não ficar completamente perdido?

Comment: Claro, que sim. Editei a resposta para incluir uma explicação. Caso necessites de mais algum detalhe avisa.

Comment: Só sobre o uso de `HAVING, COUNT e CASE`... Faz uma combinação com o total de *objecto* com os *objectos* distintos do grupo 1, é isso?

Comment: Sim, o uso do having é para garantir que todos os objectos do grupo estão no grupo 1. Editei a resposta, avisa se precisar de algum detalhe extra.

Comment: Show, entendi melhor a aplicação agora. Já havia revirado o SOEN mas nada encontrei que pudesse ajudar. Sua resposta foi direto ao ponto.

Comment: Só estou aguardando o tempo para oferecer recompensa para marcar sua resposta. Abri um [META](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4322/13412) explicando.

Answer (score 5):

## Solução:

```
select A.GRUPO
from TABELA A join TABELA B on B.OBJETO = A.OBJETO
where B.GRUPO = 1
group by A.GRUPO
having count(A.OBJETO) = (select count(OBJETO) from TABELA where GRUPO = 1)
and count(A.OBJETO) = (select count(OBJETO) from TABELA where GRUPO = A.GRUPO)
```

Esta query funciona e me parece bastante simples.

## Explicando a linha de raciocínio:

Com a primeira parte da query (do *select* até o *where*) eu retorno os registros que possuem ao menos um dos objetos do grupo 1.

Para melhor visualização, veja esta primeira parte da query ligeiramente modificada:

```
select A.ID, A.GRUPO, A.OBJETO
from TABELA A join TABELA B on B.OBJETO = A.OBJETO
where B.GRUPO = 1
```

O resultado desta query seria:

```
-------------------
ID | GRUPO | OBJETO
---|-------|-------
1  |  1    |    1
2  |  1    |    2
   |       |
3  |  2    |    1
4  |  2    |    2
   |       |
5  |  3    |    1
6  |  3    |    2
-7 |  3    |    3
   |       |
8  |  4    |    1
-9 |  4    |    3
   |       |
10 |  5    |    1
```

Os registros assinalados (**-**) ficaram de fora do resultado, dado que seu objeto não corresponde a nenhum dos objetos do grupo 1.

Então veja que até agora eu retorno somente os grupos que possuam algum objeto do grupo 1, e também o seu respectivo objeto.

Vamos agora visualizar o agrupamento disso:

```
select A.GRUPO, count(A.OBJETO)
from TABELA A join TABELA B on B.OBJETO = A.OBJETO
where B.GRUPO = 1
group by A.GRUPO
```

Resultado:

```
---------------------
GRUPO | COUNT(OBJETO)
------|--------------
  1   |     2
  2   |     2
  3   |     2
  4   |     1
  5   |     1
```

Agora eu vou filtrar para manter somente os grupos cuja totalização de objetos seja igual ao total de objetos do grupo 1, adicionando a cláusula *having*:

```
select A.GRUPO, count(A.OBJETO)
from TABELA A join TABELA B on B.OBJETO = A.OBJETO
where B.GRUPO = 1
group by A.GRUPO
-- novo:
having count(A.OBJETO) = (select count(OBJETO) from TABELA where GRUPO = 1)
```

Resultado

```
---------------------
GRUPO | COUNT(OBJETO)
------|--------------
  1   |     2
  2   |     2
  3   |     2
```

O grupo 3 tem que sair porque embora o *count* dele tenha ficado em 2 (porque ele de fato possui dois objetos coincidindo com os objetos do grupo 1), na verdade ele tem 3 objetos na base (um deles não coincide com nenhum objeto do grupo 1 e por isso ficou de fora do *count*).

Então eu adiciono mais uma condição no *having*, determinando que sejam mantidos apenas os grupos cujo total de objetos na base seja igual ao total de objetos do grupo 1:

```
select A.GRUPO, count(A.OBJETO)
from TABELA A join TABELA B on B.OBJETO = A.OBJETO
where B.GRUPO = 1
group by A.GRUPO
having count(A.OBJETO) = (select count(OBJETO) from TABELA where GRUPO = 1)
-- novo:
and count(A.OBJETO) = (select count(OBJETO) from TABELA where GRUPO = A.GRUPO)
```

Por fim, eu removo o *count* do *select* porque não desejo ele na visualização do resultado, e chego à query que foi apresentada no começo da resposta.

Veja no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f956/1/0).

Comment: Passou bem perto, mas o problema não é a quantidade equivalente, pois, por exemplo, o grupo 1 tem objeto (1 e 2) e o grupo 2 tem objeto (1 e 3)... Ambos tem o objeto **1** em comum e a mesma quantidade igual, mas não tem os mesmos objetos.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Entendi. Resolvido.

Comment: @PapaCharlie E aí, testou? Works like a charm :D

Comment: Estou testando ainda e adaptando...

Answer (score 3):

A única maneira que sei como fazer é com `GROUP_CONCAT`, e como não é possível fazer *join* com campos calculados serão necessárias duas *subqueries* (iguais, pode até criar um *view*):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
    SELECT grupo
    , GROUP_CONCAT(objeto ORDER BY objeto) objetos
    FROM tabela GROUP BY grupo
) t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT grupo
    , GROUP_CONCAT(objeto ORDER BY objeto) objetos
    FROM tabela GROUP BY grupo
) t2 on t1.objetos = t2.objetos
WHERE t1.grupo = 1
```

Fiz um [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d6f25/1) demonstrando o funcionamento com o grupo 3, que tem 3 objetos.

Comment: Mas nesse caso, `t1.objetos = t2.objetos` não retornaria caso fosse a comparação de 3 objetos - ou estou enganado? E `GROUP_CONCAT` tem o empecilho do limite, que teria que manipular...

Comment: "Independe" da quantidade, vai funcionar com 3 ou mais, por causa do `order by` dentro de `grupo_concat`, mas realmente está sujeito ao limite

Comment: Não funcionou, concatenou o grupo 3 também.

Answer (score -6):

**Segue o SQL**

```
SELECT count(distinct grupo,objecto) as tabela FROM tabela WHERE objecto in (1,2) and grupo IN (1,2) group by objecto.
```

Verifique se é isso que você quer.
Da próxima vez tente ser mais claro.

Comment: Faça um teste e descubra que `in` não retorna o registros que **contém exatamente os mesmos objetos**!