# SELECT com condição WHERE com vários valores em uma mesma coluna

Tags: mysql, select, filtro, where

Eu tenho duas tabelas no meu banco e realizo o `JOIN` com elas. Uma tabela é uma lista de pessoas e a outra lista características dessa pessoa. Pela lógica só existe uma pessoa e cada pessoa pode ter várias características, por isso duas tabelas. Então quando eu faço um `JOIN` aparece a mesma pessoa algumas vezes só que com sua característica do lado. EX:

```
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  ID |  PESSOA | CARACTERÍSTICA |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Alto           |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Divertido      |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Inteligente    |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  2  | Iago    | Baixo          |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  2  | Iago    | Divertido      |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  2  | Iago    | Esperto        |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  3  | Artur   | Divertido      |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  3  | Artur   | Inteligente    |
+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Se eu fizer o seguinte `SELECT` eu obtenho um resultado vazio:

```
SELECT 
    p.*, c.* 
FROM 
    pessoas AS p LEFT JOIN perfil AS c ON p.pid = c.perfil_pessoa 
WHERE 
    c.caracteristica = 'Divertido' AND c.caracteristica = 'Inteligente'
```

Quando na verdade eu gostaria do seguinte resultado:

```
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  ID |  PESSOA | CARACTERÍSTICA |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Alto           |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Divertido      |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Inteligente    |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  3  | Artur   | Divertido      |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  3  | Artur   | Inteligente    |
+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Ou seja, ter como resultado, toda pessoa que seja `'Divertida'` e `'Inteligente'`.

Se na cláusula `WHERE` do `SELECT` eu usar `IN` ou `OR` o resultado também não é aquilo que espero, pelo exemplo dado, o `SELECT` retornaria todos os resultados, pois todos as pessoas tem como característica "Divertido":

```
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  ID |  PESSOA | CARACTERÍSTICA |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Alto           |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Divertido      |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  1  | Carlos  | Inteligente    |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  2  | Iago    | Baixo          |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  2  | Iago    | Divertido      |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  2  | Iago    | Esperto        |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  3  | Artur   | Divertido      |
+-----+---------+----------------+
|  3  | Artur   | Inteligente    |
+-----+---------+----------------+
```

> O intuito é construir filtros usando as características das pessoas.

Comment: A ausência do modelo da tabela perfil dificulta a resposta.

Comment: Não responde diretamente a pergunta, mas por que não declarar característica como um `SET`na tabela pessoas? Mais informações em: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você quer trazer a pessoa e todas as suas características, caso atendam ao filtro (que vai ser cumulativo).

Se você estiver usando a versão **8 do MySql**, isso vai ser como um passeio no parque.

[Segundo a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), essa versão dá suporte a *Commom Table Expressions*.

<sub>*Tradução livre com destaques próprios*</sub>

> Uma *common table expression* (CTE) é um *resultset* nomeado **temporário** que **só existe dentro do escopo de uma única instrução sql**, portanto pode ser referenciado somente nela.

As aplicações e variações das CTEs são inúmeras. O seu caso certamente é uma delas.

<sup>**Nota - As tabelas e nomes de colunas foram simplificados nos exemplos a seguir**</sup>

Veja como poderíamos fazer:

```
WITH candidatos AS 
 ( 
     SELECT DISTINCT c.id_pessoa 
     FROM caracteristica c
     WHERE c.caracteristica in ('Alto','Magro') // Insere aqui a lista de qualidades procuradas
     GROUP BY c.id_pessoa
     HAVING count(Distinct c.caracteristica) >= 2 // Aqui a quantidade de qualidades filtradas
 )
SELECT p.nome, c.caracteristica
FROM candidatos filtro 
    JOIN pessoa p ON o.id = filtro.id_pessoa
    JOIN característica c ON c.id_pessoa = p.id
```

<sup>***Infelizmente não encontrei um fiddle do MySql 8 online para enriquecer a resposta com um exemplo verificável***</sup>

Parece uma consulta limpa o suficiente para mim e eu realmente espero que você possa alplicar uma solução como essa no seu cenário para o bem de todos e felicidade geral da nação.

Por outro lado...

## Se estiver usando uma versão do MySql < 8.0

Caso esteja usando versões anteriores, consegui chegar em algumas alternativas que possam resolver seu problema, mas continuar em busca de alternativas melhores é recomendado.

**Opção 1 - Usando alguns selects aninhados:**

```
SELECT P.nome, C.caracteristica
FROM PESSOA P
    JOIN CARACTERISTICA C on C.id_pessoa = P.id
WHERE Exists ( SELECT 1
               FROM CARACTERISTICA C2
                    RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT distinct cr.caracteristica
                                 FROM caracteristica cr
                                 WHERE Cr.CARACTERISTICA in ('Alto', 'Magro') ) c1 ON c2.caracteristica = c1.caracteristica
              WHERE c2.id_pessoa = p.id 
              GROUP BY C2.id_pessoa
              HAVING count(c2.caracteristica) >= ( SELECT Count(distinct cr.caracteristica)
                                                   FROM caracteristica cr
                                                   WHERE Cr.CARACTERISTICA in ('Alto', 'Magro') ) )
```

** Ainda há um problema aqui nos subselects eu uso um `Distinct` nas características para obter um subconjunto com os valores `Alto` e `Magro`. Caso você incluísse como filtro uma característica que ninguém tinha (`Feio`, por exemplo), essa condição seria simplesmente 'ignorada' no resultado. Acho que esse não seria o comportamento esperado/ideal.*

*** [Este exemplo está disponível no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/898d4/50)**

**Opção 2 - -Usando tabela temporária:**

Um outro caminho seria usar uma tabela temporária e inserir nela as características desejadas. A consulta ficaria menos feia (mas ainda longe do ideal), assim:

```
SELECT P.nome, C.caracteristica
FROM PESSOA P
  JOIN CARACTERISTICA C on C.id_pessoa = P.id
  JOIN ( SELECT c2.id_pessoa, count(c2.caracteristica)
         FROM filtro f
             LEFT JOIN caracteristica c2 on c2.caracteristica = f.caracteristica
         GROUP BY c2.id_pessoa
         HAVING COUNT(c2.caracteristica) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filtro) ) pf on pf.id_pessoa = p.id
```

*** [Este exemplo também está disponível no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2af661/1)**

## Sobre os resultados que você teve na sua tentativa

Quando você declara da maneira que você havia feito (No `Where` da própria consulta `c.caracteristica = 'Divertido' AND c.caracteristica = 'Inteligente'`) você estava recebendo o resultado vazio porque cada característica tinha que ser igual a 'Inteligente' **E** igual a 'Divertido', o que é conceitualmente impossível, pois a característica será sempre **um** ou **outro**.

Usando `IN` ou `OR` (também no `Where` da própria consulta, como ficou sugerido) você acabaria trazendo somente as características **filtradas** e de qualquer pessoa que **possuísse pelo menos uma delas**.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: você entendeu perfeitamente o que quero fazer, só que fiz um teste aqui seguindo seu exemplo, e ainda sim retornou todos os resultados que possui uma característica ou outra, não necessariamente o resultado que tenha ambas características selecionadas.

Comment: Agora funcionou! Muito obrigado, vou aplicar ao projeto.

Comment: 'buscar alternativas é bem recomendado', você teria alguma pra me indicar? Pesquisei sobre esse tipo de filtro na internet e não encontrei nada que pudesse me guiar pra um cenário ideal.

Comment: Acredito que não haja um recurso já implementado para este problema de [Divisão Relacional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)), as soluções muito provavelmente serão variações do que já ofereci, mas talvez mais eficientes. Mas vou manter isso em mente, caso encontre uma _solução canônica_ volto aqui para compartilhá-la. A própria comunidade aqui pode oferecê-la daqui um tempo.

Comment: Ah! [Este artigo](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) discute o problema e apresenta algumas implementações. Vale a pena dar uma conferida!

Comment: Eu usei a primeira solução, realmente funcionou perfeitamente. De fato o comando ficou bem complexo, mas funciona. Obrigado.

Comment: Diego, poderia me da mais uma ajuda? Coloquei mais informações no chat com o novo obstaculo que encontrei

Comment: @ivanveloso não conheço o mecanismo do fullsearch mas [na documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) vi que há algumas restrições, como quando eles citam _'words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match'_. Talvez seja o caso de você [usá-lo no modo booleano](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) (`MATCH (p.product_name) AGAINST ('idem' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`), que não possui restrição. Não sei dizer ao certo.

Answer (score 10):

Tem maneiras e maneiras de fazer, qual a melhor, depende de como serão geradas as *queries*.

Para o seu caso provavelmente eu preferiria ter uma tabela de características, uma de pessoas, e uma terceira para fazer as relações. Independente disto, seguem algumas alternativas para a sua modelagem atual:

## Usando `JOIN`:

Esta é uma maneira relativamente simples e objetiva - fazer um `JOIN` para cada característica:

```
SELECT 
    a.caracteristica,
    b.caracteristica,
    p.pessoa
FROM 
    perfil AS a
    LEFT JOIN perfil AS b ON a.perfil_pessoa = b.perfil_pessoa
    LEFT JOIN pessoa AS p ON a.perfil_pessoa = p.pid
WHERE 
    a.caracteristica = 'Divertido' AND
    b.caracteristica = 'Inteligente'
;
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93f85e/1)**.

Apesar de precisar de um número de `JOIN`s equivalente ao número de características, o uso do `LEFT` já permite que um planner eficiente elimine em cascata os ítens que não atendem a qualquer das características.

## Usando `SUM`, `IF` e `HAVING` para filtrar a contagem de ítens:

O "segredo" aqui é fazer a comparação do `SUM` com o número de ítens buscados (meio que inspirado na solução do colega @bruno):

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(caracteristica ORDER BY caracteristica) AS caracteristicas,
  pessoa
FROM
  pessoa
  JOIN perfil ON perfil_pessoa = pid
GROUP BY
  pid
HAVING
  SUM(IF(caracteristica IN ('Divertido','Inteligente'),1,0))=2
;
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94c4cd/1)**.

Mas esta opção tem um perigo: Caso hajam duas entradas 'Divertido' para a mesma pessoa, ela não funcionará. Tenha o cuidado de garantir a unicidade de opções neste caso (ou use um DISTINCT). Veja a solução avançada a seguir:

## Versão "avançada" do `HAVING`:

Esta versão usa a mesma técnica da anterior, mas com matemática de bits, garantindo que todos os termos sejam encontrados independente de posição, ordem de listagem na busca ou número de ocorrências.

Usando o `FIND_IN_SET` passamos a detectar em que posição da lista está o termo buscado, setando um bit usando a função de agregação `BIT_AND`:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(caracteristica ORDER BY caracteristica) AS caracteristicas,
  pessoa
FROM
  pessoa
  JOIN perfil ON perfil_pessoa = pid
GROUP BY
  pid
HAVING
  BIT_OR(POW(2,FIND_IN_SET(caracteristica, 'Divertido,Inteligente')))&6=6
;
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5550a/1)**.

A parte mais complexa é determinar o &6=6 no final da *query*. O `FIND_IN_SET` retorna valores na faixa de 0 ao número de ítens do SET passado em *string*. Zero significa "não encontrado".

Para setar os *bits* nós usamos o `POW(2,...)`. Ou seja, se nada for encontrado, será setado o bit `0b00000001`. Se for encontrado o primeiro termo, será setado o bit `0b00000010`, e assim por diante.

Acontece que queremos o primeiro e o segundo termos, o que dá o valor binário `0b00000110`, que é justamente 6. Temos que ignorar o primeiro bit, pois ele será setado caso seja retornado um termo diferente do buscado (e o primeiro bit não será setado caso a *query* encontre exatamente os termos buscados).

Assim, fazendo `&6`, obtemos o valor 6 estando ou não o último bit setado. Relembrando: palavra não encontrada é o bit zero (valor 1). Termo 1 é o bit 2 (2 em decimal). Termo 2 é o bit 3 (4 em decimal). Portanto 2 + 4 = 6.

E se fossem 3 termos? Mesma lógica, 2 + 4 + 8 = 14, então a expressão do `HAVING` seria `&14=14`. Se fossem 4 termos? 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 30, ficando `&30=30` no `HAVING`.

Tenho que calcular "na mão"? Não, basta usar a fórmula a seguir:

```
bitfield = ( 2 ^ num_termos - 1 ) * 2
```

Isso pode ser útil na linguagem cliente para gerar a *query*.

## Usando `GROUP_CONCAT`:

Esta *query* é versátil na hora de gerar os filtros no sentido de não precisar de `JOIN`s extra (entretanto, na prática, ter vários `JOIN`s não deve ser um problema real neste contexto):

```
SELECT
  pessoa, caracteristicas
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(caracteristica) AS caracteristicas,
      pessoa
    FROM
      pessoa JOIN perfil ON perfil_pessoa = pid
    GROUP BY
      pid
  ) c
WHERE
  CONCAT(',',caracteristicas,',') LIKE "%,Divertido,%" AND
  CONCAT(',',caracteristicas,',') LIKE "%,Inteligente,%"
;
```

Perceba que a *query* ficaria muito mais simples sem o `CONCAT(','`, mas isto é um bom hábito quando você busca múltiplas *strings*, para evitar que um `LIKE "%amigo%"` pegue um `amigo-da-onça` por engano.

A "vantagem" aqui é que você só mexe no WHERE, independente do número de características.

A desvantagem é que a busca é feita com `LIKE` e não aproveita índices.

Veja funcionando no **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8676cc/1)**.

Comment: +1 Gosto principalmente da primeira alternativa

Comment: @bruno grato!. De fato, a 1a é tecnicamente mais elegante. Ficaria mais legível se eu trocasse por RIGHT JOIN (os joins seriam as condições, e a "pessoa" o primeiro membro do SELECT), mas acabei deixando mais parecida com o que eu quero que o _query planner_ faça. Eu gosto de opções para mostrar várias características úteis para outras situações.

Comment: @bruno apelei, veja a do HAVING com binário :D

Comment: Excelente!  Acredito que todas essas opções podem ser reproduzidas em outros sgbd também,  as cartas estão na mesa =)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza depois melhoro. Tem umas funções que não são universais, mas tem substituto. Por exemplo, o IF vira IIF em alguns SGBDs (creio que no T-SQL é IIF, por exemplo)

Comment: Sim, quando eu disse que os recursos podem ser_reproduzidos_ quis dizer que são _traduzíveis, convertíveis_ ou pelo menos tem um _recurso equivalente_ nos outros. No caso das CTE que eu propus muitos bancos não tem.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza eu não sei se todos tem essa parte de agregação binária da opção 3, de fato. O resto eu acredito ser bem portável mesmo

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza grato pelo incentivo, em me ocorrendo mais alternativas interessantes, complemento a resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Este é um (des)conhecido problema chamado de "Relational Division" (estou a tentar encontrar fontes em portugues mas está complicado) em que o objectivo é encontrar registos que respeitem um conjunto de critérios. Já existem algumas perguntas semelhantes aqui no SOPt, [por exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84084/24340)

Neste caso em particular, é pretendido identificar as pessoas que possuem (**entre outros**) os atributos "Magro" e "Alto".

Baseada na resposta do Diego Rafael Souza, fica aqui uma versão com um comportamento um pouco diferente.

```
SELECT C.ID_PESSOA, 
       P.NOME,
       C.CARACTERISTICA
  FROM PESSOA P
 INNER JOIN CARACTERISTICA C
    ON C.ID_PESSOA = P.ID
 WHERE C.ID_PESSOA IN
 (
    SELECT ID_PESSOA
      FROM CARACTERISTICA C
     WHERE CARACTERISTICA IN ('Magro', 'Alto')
     GROUP BY ID_PESSOA
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CARACTERISTICA) = 2
 );
```

Neste caso note que, ao contrário das duas primeiras alternativas propostas, apenas serão retornadas as pessoas que são ao mesmo tempo "Magro" e "Alto". A principal diferença está nesta instrução:

```
HAVING count(c2.caracteristica) >= ( SELECT Count(distinct cr.caracteristica)
                                       FROM caracteristica cr
                                      WHERE Cr.CARACTERISTICA in ('Alto', 'Magro') ) )
```

Se na sua base de dados não existir qualquer pessoa que tenha o atributo "Magro", irão ser incluidas no conjunto de resultados todas as pessoas que são "Alto" e "Gordo", por exemplo.

Pode confirmar no seguinte [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f3118/1).

No seu caso, precisa mesmo de forçar que o número de caracteristicas seja 2, da forma `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CARACTERISTICA) = 2` ou, como o Diego fez na terceira opção, usando uma tabela temporária e contando o número de registos existentes.

Se necessitar de uma solução mais genérica o uso da tabela temporária ou *table variable* é uma boa idea e ao mesmo tempo deverá ter uma boa performance:

```
CREATE TABLE FILTRO(f varchar(30));

INSERT INTO FILTRO(f) VALUES('Alto'),('Magro');

SELECT C.ID_PESSOA, 
       P.NOME,
       C.CARACTERISTICA
  FROM PESSOAS P
 INNER JOIN perfil C
    ON C.ID_PESSOA = P.ID
 WHERE C.ID_PESSOA IN
 (
    SELECT ID_PESSOA
      FROM PERFIL 
     WHERE CARACTERISTICA IN ('Magro', 'Alto')
     GROUP BY ID_PESSOA
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CARACTERISTICA) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM FILTRO)
 );
```

Comment: Ótima referêrencia para a pergunta aqui do SOpt, eu havia procurando antes e não tinha encontrado.

Answer (score 1):

Estou postando nesta data, só pra ajudar quem precise de uma consulta mais simplificada para atender a mesma situação.

Tabela unica = pessoa

SQL=

```
   select  P.nome, P.caracteristica
    from 
       pessoa P
      ,(SELECT id from pessoa where caracteristica='Alto') as C1
      ,(SELECT id from pessoa where caracteristica='Inteligente') as C2
    where 
      P.id=C1.id 
      AND P.id=C2.id
```

Cada caracteristica tem que ser criada uma nova subconsulta  Exemplo: ,`(SELECT id from pessoa where caracteristica='Divertido') as C3`
e na clausura `where` incluir `AND P.id=C3.id`

NOVA SQL=

```
   select  P.nome, P.caracteristica
    from 
       pessoa P
      ,(SELECT id from pessoa where caracteristica='Alto') as C1
      ,(SELECT id from pessoa where caracteristica='Inteligente') as C2
      ,(SELECT id from pessoa where caracteristica='Divertido') as C3
    where 
      P.id=C1.id 
      AND P.id=C2.id
      AND P.id=C3.id
```

Answer (score 1):

- A ausência do modelo da tabela perfil dificulta a resposta, mas:

FROM
pessoas AS p LEFT JOIN perfil AS c ON p.pid = c.perfil_pessoa

- Um dos erros estão logo acima, o c.perfil_pessoa tem que ser o c.id para o id do p.id receber o id do perfil.

veja:

FROM
pessoas p
left join caracteristica c on c.id = p.id

no where voce pode usar o IN

FROM
pessoas p
left join caracteristica c on c.id = p.id
WHERE
c.caracteristica IN ('Divertido', 'Inteligente')