# MySQL - Como obter resultados que não foram encontrados

Tags: mysql

Preciso de verificar quais foram os IDs que não foram encontrados na tabela.

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id IN (123, 124, 125, 126, 127)
```

Sendo que dos `(123, 124, 125, 126, 127)`, na tabela só tenho `(123, 124)`.

O resultado que estou a espera é `(125, 126, 127)`.

Explorei a opção das Sub-querys mas não consigo perceber como hei de terminar.

Comment: A ideia era fazer isto tudo numa query de MySQL. Mas a linguagem é C#.

Comment: Tem que haver alguma saída que me autorize colocar a "lista" de valores e receber qual destes valores não esta na tabela.

Comment: Todas vezes que precisei fazer isso. Eu criei uma tabela e populei com todos os valores, então eu consigo selecionar todos os itens dessa tabela que não tem na outra.

Comment: Para SQLite eu tenho essa solução. Traduzir para o MySql deve dar um pouco de trabalho: SELECT A.X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(123) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X < (127)) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CAST( id AS NUMBER ) AS id FROM example_table WHERE id >= 123 and ID <= 127 ) B
ON A.X = B.id
WHERE B.id IS NULL
LIMIT ( 123 - 127 + 1 )

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo a depender da versão do `MySql` é bem assim mesmo, o [MySql 8.0 dá suporte a CTE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295382/select-com-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-where-com-v%C3%A1rios-valores-em-uma-mesma-coluna/295384#295384)

Answer (score 0):

Lembrando que a seguinte solução se encaixa quando a necessidade de uso for algo que se compara ao que for utilizado em `NOT IN, IN`. Algo com pouco valores. 
Veja se desta forma, te ajuda em algo:

```
SELECT ids.id FROM (SELECT '123' AS id
                    UNION SELECT '124'
                    UNION SELECT '125' 
                    UNION SELECT '126'
                    UNION SELECT '127') ids
LEFT JOIN example_table ex
  ON ex.id = ids.id
WHERE ex.id IS NULL
```

Saída:

```
id
125
126
127
```

Eu testei aqui. Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25451956/3658278

Comment: Digamos que eu tenha uma tabela com numeros, onde o menor é o numero 1 e o maior é o 1.000.000. Sei que entre esses numeros existem vazios. Como utilizo esse select para me mostrar quais são os numeros faltantes?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Sim, entendo. A mesma regra vale para `id IN (123, 124, 125, 126, 127)`, não? Quando se usa IN, NOT IN. Nestes casos, também não se pode usar de 1 à 1.000.000 Concorda comigo? A resposta é no intuito de ajudar com base numa outra resposta aqui mesmo do stackoverflow, a qual ninguém foi lá negativar. Voltando ao tópico aqui. A referência é para solução dentro de uma matriz com poucos valores.

Comment: Resposta editada para salientar onde uma instrução assim se adaptaria.